# Filter SYSDATE on Julian JDE Date

Tags: sql, oracle, julian-date

I would like to add a filter to my SELECT * query, to get just values, that are below the current SYSDATE.
The column with Julian JDE Dates is [JDate]. It has a structure like CYYDDD.

Something like this:

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(JDate, 2), 'RRDDD') < SYSDATE
```

Is not working.

Does someone now how to filter here in the WHERE place to get the necessary data?

Comment: Just saying it isn't working isn't very helpful; do you get an error, or wrong results? It would be useful to include some sample values in your question, and which should and should not be matched by the filter.

Comment: Query itself looks OK, so - maybe it is about data you're dealing with?

Comment: What is the error you get and what is the data type of JDate?

Comment: Thank you guys! There is no error. Instead of 180001 for 2080.01.01 I get 1980.01.01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct CYYDDD format for the current date as:

```
floor((extract(year from sysdate) - 1900) / 100) || to_char(sysdate, 'RRDDD')
```

You can then use this in a `WHERE` clause:

```
jdate < floor((extract(year from sysdate) - 1900) / 100) || to_char(sysdate, 'RRDDD')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But this will show me 220308 as the sysdate. But today is 120308 in our system.

Comment: @joshua . . . You can subtract 1900 instead.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: @joshua - you had been asked before to provide the data type of the column JDATE.  Knowing this is critical to providing an optimal solution.